# use var to set offset position in SVG gradient

Tags: css, svg, css-variables

I am using a gradient to fill an svg path.
like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 40">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="progress-gradient" x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="var(--offset-empty)" stopColor="var(--color-empty)" />
      <stop offset="var(--offset-full)" stopColor="var(--color-full)" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="..removed" fill="url(#progress-gradient)" />
</svg>
```

and I am styling it with css:

```
#progress-gradient {
    --color-empty: #ffffff;
    --color-full: #ff0000;
    --offset-empty: 50%;
    --offset-full: 100%;
}
```

I am trying to set the offsets dynamically to create a kind of progress within the SVG icon.
But this isn't working. Colors are working, but not offset.
Is there any other way I can dynamically set the offset positions with CSS?

many thanks

Comment: offset is [an attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#GradientStops), it's not a CSS property so you can't use CSS variables to set it.

Comment: @RobertLongson so is stopColor, yet I'm able to change that with var().

Comment: stopColor is a CSS property, offset is not.